# Similarity percentage of documents using mongoose

Tags: mongoose, aggregation

I have to calculate the most suitable match for a particular user on the basis of their preferences, such as:

```
_id: "1",
name:"Bob",
"foodLiked": ["Seafood", "Thai", "Italian"]
}
then there is another user:
{
_id: "2",
name:"Ben",
"foodLiked": ["Seafood", "Thai", "Indian"]
}
and,
{
_id: "3",
name:"Jo",
"foodLiked": ["Seafood", "chinese", "Indian"]
}
```

So, 
Ben is 66% similar to Bob, Jo is 33% similar to Bob. How can I achieve it using mongoose aggregate?